Unity NullReferenceException even though I see it's not in the debugger
This is the full error:

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
object.

Variable activeWeapon is set to an instance in the Unity editor.
The problem occurs when setting the bullet.transform.position.
I can follow the Debugger and see that activeWeapon is not null when I step into and after that line.
But when I step out of the function, then I get the error above.
Even when I use activeWeapon.transform I get the same error.
Using the player's transform shoots the bullet from the player, and not from the active weapon's position.
public void weaponAttack()
{
    GameObject bullet = ObjPoolWeapon.Instance.GetPooledObj();
    //Vector3 spawnLocation = activeWeapon.transform.position + activeWeapon.spawnLocationWM;
    **bullet.transform.position = activeWeapon.spawnLocationGO.transform.position;**
    bullet.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
    bullet.SetActive(true);
}



This is usually a sign that you have more than one instance of this script running. One is configured correctly: that's the one you're inspecting with the debugger. The other is not configured correctly: that's the one that's throwing the error, leading to the apparent paradox of an error that's not present when inspected.

Ahhh okay then that's would make sense. I'll have to double check. The player has a weapons manager script. And the weapons inherit from that script.

Weapons inherit from WeaponManager? That seems like an unusual arrangement.

I'm not creative on names but at least for the moment it's helped to keep things as decoupled as I can possibly think of while allowing me to just pass in a weapon object and call the same method for that specific object.

The first comment did indeed help me to solve this. there were two instances running, one was not null like I saw in the debugger and the other was
